# Parsing PHP embedded in XML

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, processing-instruction

I read [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973059/embedding-php-in-xml) however there wasn't any mention of it being a "bad idea", and unfortunately any search query with the words **parse**, **xml**, and **php** typically yield information about parsing XML with PHP (*via [SimpleXML](http://ca.php.net/simplexml) or whatever*)

> *Short question* -- Is it a viable solution to embed PHP in XML, extracting (*and executing*) it conditionally, by targeting processing instruction nodes during XML parsing, or am I barking up a tree fraught with issues?
>
> *Expanding* -- Perhaps the issue is less to do with XML, and more to do with selecting an appropriate "meta-language", against which I can perform queries to satisfy conditions, and execute the contained PHP snippet. XML seemed like a good candidate for it's structure, portability, and simplicity (*despite verbosity*)
> I've considered just falling back to vanilla PHP, using arrays as a data structure, but any structured meta-language would suffice as a wrapper. Suggestions of your preferred language for such a task is more than welcome.

Anyway, I've been working on an engine that accepts XML files with embedded PHP. I parse the XML data (*in my case using SAX callbacks*) and depending on some input to assist with "querying" the XML data, the appropriate embedded PHP is pulled and ran with `eval()`.

(*I know; "If `eval()` is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the wrong question.", but I'm not concerned with that at the moment*)

So I end up with something like:

```
<root>
    <node>
        <parameters>
            <!-- some stuff -->
        </parameters>
        <callback>
            <?php
                function(){
                    // do some stuff
                };
            ?>
        </callback>
    </node>
    <node>
        <parameters>
            <!-- some other stuff -->
        </parameters>
        <callback>
            <?php
                function(){
                    // do some other stuff
                };
            ?>
        </callback>
    </node>
</root>
```

I can parse the PHP out by setting a callback with `xml_set_processing_instruction_handler()` which ultimately does:

```
xml_set_processing_instruction_handler($parser, function($parser, $target, $func)
    {
        // obtain some parameters into $data
        call_user_func(eval("return {$func};"), $data);
    });
```

(*the code is only an example, there's alot more going on here of course*)

Has this approach been attempted resulting in failure due to some unforeseen
edge case? I don't want to invest a large about of time into such a parser only to find out that it'll fail spectacularly under some circumstances. I'm happy to learn from my own mistakes, but I'd much rather learn from someone else's.

Comment: Ensure that you're using <![CDATA[...]]> around the embedded PHP in your XML, and take a look at other tools that use similar techniques, such as phing

Comment: Thanks @MarkBaker -- I'll definitely look into the Phing docs/source for such information (*if you know of any other tools that use this technique, I'd love to know of them*) Regarding the wrapping with `<![CDATA]` blocks though; will that not negate the processing instruction parsing technique?

Comment: Since php is string-based, it's very easy for your output to become invalid XML. You may want to attempt to parse the generated string, or force the PHP to return nodes instead of strings.

Comment: Using <![CDATA[ should present any problems with certain characters that can easily appear in php, but can confuse parsing the xml markup e.g. < > braces

Comment: Per [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-chardata), these characters can appear unescaped in PI sections. Also, "PIs are not part of the document's character data" (§2.6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a better approach than Phing's custom approach of declaring an [AdhocTask](http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/trunk/chapters/appendixes/AppendixB-CoreTasks.html#AdhocTaskdefTask) as CDATA and executing the code within. Note that in the [source code](http://svn.phing.info/trunk/classes/phing/tasks/system/AdhocTask.php), they simply eval the contents of the element.

One caveat that I can see is mentioned on the [xml_set_processing_instruction_handler() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.xml-set-processing-instruction-handler.php): "the PI end tag (?>) can not be quoted." This means the following will present a problem:

```
<callback>
    <?php
        function() {
            return '?>';
        };
    ?>
</callback>
```

This is quite easily avoided:

```
<callback>
    <?php
        function() {
            return '?' . '>';
        };
    ?>
</callback>
```

Other than that, as long as you take [the usual eval() precautions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php), you should be fine!

Comment: Thanks @cbuckley -- That is an edge case very much worth mentioning. While I don't expect that to be an issue, I'm thinking perhaps the CDATA approach may then be better. Taking advantage of processing instruction parsing though, seems like the nicest solution. Besides writing a *gotcha* in the library docs outlining your example, what considerations could I make to help avoid this possible issue? (*the XML files will be written by client-programmers, so as I mentioned, I'd have to make note of this caveat in the docs, but I'd rather make it foolproof if possible*)

Comment: CDATA has the same caveat with its own closing delimiter, `]]>`. Nothing is foolproof to the sufficiently qualified fool :-)

Comment: Thanks again @cbuckley -- True enough; since the PHP snippet needs to be located in a certain element anyway (*`callback` in my example, but I'm still deciding*) perhaps I could permit either format (*CDATA or PI*) and let the client choose (*like single or double quotes*) the most appropriate. As my recent edit goes on to say, I'm interested in using XML as it's a tested and true language with alot of support, but any suggestions for other "meta-languages" with which I could encapsulate PHP are more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

For understand the use of *"parsing PHP embedded in XSLT"* see [this tutorial of registerPHPFunctions](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/PHP_Programming/XSL/registerPHPFunctions).

For understand the use of *"PHP into XML"* (as usual use of PHP "into HTML") see http://code.google.com/p/smallest-php-xml-xsl-framework/      
It is an application with XML+PHP (PHP generating XML) and XSLT as optional template system.  In a MVC architecture the XML+PHP do the "MVC-Model processing"  and  XSLT the MVC-View (or optional direct use of a PHP code as View).